# Does anyone know why this php iteration won't work

Tags: php, loops, iteration, while-loop

Does anyone know why this doesn't work

```
function my_current($array) {
    return current($array);
}

$array = array(1,3,5,7,13);

while($i = my_current($array)) {
    $content .= $i.',';
    next($array);
}
```

yet this does

```
$array = array(1,3,5,7,13);

while($i = current($array)) {
    $content .= $i.',';
    next($array);
}
```

or how to make the top one work?
It's a little question but it would be a big help!
Thanks
Richard

Comment: Could you please post current() function? Could you post the error? Anyway it is probably a scope problem.

Comment: What is the function current() doing? Is it a mistype or an actual function?

Comment: @hollsk `current` is a core PHP array function.  It returns the value of the array element that's currently being pointed to by the internal pointer.  http://us.php.net/current

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a copy of the array is being made.

Try this:

```
function my_current(&$array) {
    return current($array);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The array is copied, which means that the current pointer is lost. Pass it as a reference.

```
function my_current(&$array) {
```

Or better yet, use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Comment: I have note seen that before - but I knew there would be an answer!

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's because when you call a function with an array parameter, the array is copied over. Try using references.

```
function my_current(&$array) {
    return current($array);
}
```

Notice the `&`.